# Php inside php to process custom field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a code which returns gallery number 1 with the set of images.

```
<?php echo photo_gallery(1); ?>
```

But I need to change number "1" to number "2", "3" and so on with custom fields in every post using this code

```
<?php the_field('number'); ?>
```

inside the first code

I need something like this:

```
<?php echo photo_gallery(   <?php the_field('number'); ?>   ); ?>
```

Result:

```
<?php echo photo_gallery(2); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo photo_gallery(3); ?>
```

Comment: please pass what the_field('images') returns, and no need to open php tag again, just store the the_field('images') in variable and pass inside function. @user3369654

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: look the question again please

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php
echo photo_gallery(the_field('images'));
?>
```

Comment: result is "1"... not the photo.

Comment: What does the function `photo_gallery()` expect? an array? a what?

Comment: photo_gallery(1)
photo_gallery(2)
photo_gallery(3)
photo_gallery(4)
...
returns a gallery of images created by the plugin.

with the code the_field('number') i can use custom field in every post to change numbers (1,,2,3...)

Comment: ok, so if `photo_gallery()` is expecting a number, such as `1`, what does `the_field("images")` return..?

Comment: ? Just running `the_field("images")` returns what exactly?

Comment: the_field("images") returns number as i select in custom field (1,2,3...)

Comment: You should edit your question with some more example code

Comment: changed. look please.

Comment: <?php echo photo_gallery("<?php the_field('gallery_number'); ?>"); ?>
not works

Answer (score 0):

You don't need nested PHP tags. Omit the php tags inside and your code should run.

```
<?php 
echo photo_gallery(get_field('number'));
?>
```

Note the difference between [`get_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) and [`the_field`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/). ACF docs explain which to use in which situation.

Essentially, the functions inside (to the right) get executed first, returning a value which can be used by the outer function (to the left).

In the background, a programming language takes these steps:

1. execute `get_field('one')` and `return 1`.
2. execute `photo_gallery(1)` and `return (photo)`.
3. `echo (photo)`

There are some courses on PHP, many of which are free - that might help you sort through some of these issues.

Comment: But it returns only "1" and page stop loading.

Comment: <?php echo photo_gallery(1); ?> works
<?php the_field('number'); ?> works
<?php echo photo_gallery(the_field('number')); ?> not works

Comment: I updated - the_field, according to docs, echos. You want get_field.

Comment: thank you very much. Now everything is work. Can you please also tell me how to make this:
if 'number' is empty field 
not process photo_gallery()

Comment: <?php 
$gn = get_field('gallerynumber');
if (!empty($gn)) { echo photo_gallery(get_field('gallerynumber')); } 
?>

Comment: That should do it, but you can use $gn instead of a second get_field() function if you want. A bit cleaner. If it worked please consider voting for my answer. Thanks!