# Php code inside php code in wordpress using custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, gallery, advanced-custom-fields

I have a code which returns gallery number 1 with the set of images.

```
<?php echo photo_gallery(1); ?>
```

But I need to change number "1" to number "2", "3" and so on with custom fields in every post using this code

```
<?php the_field('number'); ?>
```

inside the first code

I need something like this:

```
<?php echo photo_gallery(   <?php the_field('number'); ?>   ); ?>
```

Result:

```
<?php echo photo_gallery(2); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo photo_gallery(3); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php inside php to process custom field in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703924/php-inside-php-to-process-custom-field-in-wordpress)

Comment: Please do not post the same question more than once.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a custom field `number`, your code should be the following:

```
<?php echo photo_gallery( get_the_field( 'number' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the post and then after give the number then follow the code like

```
$cnt=1;
$queryarry=array( 'post_type' => 'post' ,'posts_per_page' => 9);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  echo photo_gallery($cnt);
  $cnt++;
endwhile;
```

try this